# Leaflet.draw and Leaflet.edit has Cpu consumption very high?

Tags: leaflet

I need to draw (or edit) a line/polyline to the map.

So i add points with the draw mode.

But the last move to add the last point is strangely Cpu consumer.

With this example : https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html

I increase the size to the map in 1600*1200 for increase Cpu consumption.

In the embeded browser, draw or edit is blocking because cpu core is at 100%... (ATOM)

But with the classic browser, CPU increase too (25% for one core i7)...

It's a bug ?

EDIT :

Leaflet version : 1.0.3

Leaflet Draw version : 0.4.9

Browser : Chrome or Firefox

OS/Platform : Win10 or linux 4.9.0

Classic test : Win 10 with Chrome browser

Embeded test : Linux 4.9.0 with embeded Chrome browser

Comment: Please clarify your question.What do you mean with "embedded browser"? What do you mean with "classic browser"? Give versions if possible. Give information about your hardware as well. I do not notice any CPU impact when closing a polygon using Chrome in that example.

Comment: Also, use the profiling tools present in modern web browsers to identify performance bottlenecks.

Comment: @Senshi : Do not close a polygon, just move the last point in the map and during this time, CPU increase.

Comment: Still not an issue for me. I get about 2-3% CPU usage while moving the mouse with an active line/poly tool, but that's not surprising, because the last segment is being redrawn on every mousemove. When hovering over the final point and when closing the poly, the CPU drops back to near-zero.

Comment: Yes, if you have a i7 and you take this example. But if you take a Atom or increase the map to 1600*1200, the CPU increase too. With the little config, drawing is not possible...